# Adding each element in a list to the previous one

Tags: list-manipulation

Having a list as follow:

```
l = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5};
```

I want to add each element with the element before, so I did:

```
Delete[Table[l[[i]] + l[[i - 1]], {i, Length[l]}], 1]
```

which gives:

```
{x1 + x2, x2 + x3, x3 + x4, x4 + x5}
```

I wonder if there is a better way of doing this? or is there any built-in function to do such operation?

Comment: Have a look at `MovingMap`.

Comment: `BlockMap` with `Plus`

Comment: @William  I have no access to a computer now so I cannot experiment and make sure. BTW, I am talking about `BlockMap`, not  `MovingMap`.

Comment: Also  `Partition`. `Plus` and `Apply`.

Comment: And `MovingAverage`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So using the comments I get:

```
MovingMap[Total, l, 1]
```

that gives:

```
{x1 + x2, x2 + x3, x3 + x4, x4 + x5}
```

Comment: `ListCorrelate[]`/`ListConvolve[]` ought to be faster than this one.

Answer (score 1):

Let me make a collection of methods suggested so far, other than `MovingMap` (thx to @J.M.iscomputer-less for the last two):

```
2 MovingAverage[l, 2]
BlockMap[Total, l, 2, 1]
Total /@ Partition[l, 2, 1]
ListCorrelate[{1, 1}, l]
ListConvolve[{1, 1}, l]
```